# How to check whether the audio is available offline?

Tags: ios, audio, download

When I click on the button audio is loaded each time. How to play audio immediately if it has already been uploaded?

```
- (void) song{
if (_index1 == 0) {
    NSString *stringURL = @"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B6zMam2kAK39UjJuTHB5QWRuRU0";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if ( urlData )
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"music.mp3"];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] error:nil];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have code that always saves to a file "music.mp3" in the documents directory. 
(You should use NSString methods for dealing with a path rather than stringWithFormat. Take a look at `stringByAppendingPathComponent`. It handles the details of building a path string for you.)

I gather you're only dealing with a single sound file then?

If you want to check if a file exists you need to create an instance of `NSFileManager` and use one of it's `fileExists` methods like `fileExistsAtPath`. If the file exists, skip the download and simply load and play the file.

Note that you should NOT use dataWithContentsOfURL to download a file from the web. That's a synchronous call that will block the UI until the download is complete. You should use `NSURLSession` instead. You could create an `NSURLDownloadTask` and download the file directly to disk, then invoke a block of code once the download is complete.

Take a look at the `NSURLSession` `sharedSession` and `downloadTaskWithURL` methods.

Ray Wenderlich has a tutorial on using `NSURLSession` and `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`:

[**NSURLSession Tutorial**](https://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial)

Comment: Could you give an example from my code, please. I can not do it.

Comment: "give an example from my code" sounds more like "could you write my code for me." You certainly cannot do it if you don't try. Why don't you go through the Ray Wenderlich tutorial I linked in my answer, do the exercises, and then see if you can work out how to write code for your project? If you have trouble, post your updated code and we can help you fix it.

Comment: @Dark, Which part are you having trouble with? Using `NSFileManger` to see if the file exists, or rewriting your code to use NSURLSession rather than `dataWithContentsOfURL` to download the file?